# HTML collapsible list with references to files

Tags: html

I am new here and have a question regarding collapsible lists in html. I need to code a collapsible list on a school website page that holds a collection of "Minutes" and "Agendas" (they're just pdf files that have been uploaded to the site).

My assignment was to put them all in a collapsible list so the page does not become indefinitely lengthy. We will be adding a new "Minute" pdf and a new "Agenda" pdf every month, so I will just edit the code to include the new files.

I have created a drop-down menu with references to websites and a go button but have never gone about a collapsible list. I guess I would have two headings (one for Minutes and one for Agendas) then you click either one of those and all the pdf documents will show in chronological order.

If you were to click the pdf link it should download as that is how it is on the page right now. I tried to give as much detail as possible as to what I am trying to accomplish.

**New Edit** here is what I have so far as of now 4/23:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function toggle(divName){
if(document.getElementById)
{
var theDiv = document.getElementById(divName);
if(theDiv)
{
if(theDiv.style.display == 'none')
{
theDiv.style.display = 'block';
}
else
{
theDiv.style.display = 'none';
}
}
}
}
//]]>
</script>
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:toggle('Minutes')">Advisory Board Minutes</a>
<ul id="Minutes">
<li><a href="http://www.cnn.com">Advisory Board Minutes 1</li></a>
<li>Advisory Board Minutes 2</li>
<li>Advisory Board Minutes 3</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:toggle('Agendas')">Advisory Board Agendas</a>
<ul id="Agendas">
<li>Advisory Board Agenda 1</li>
<li>Advisory Board Agenda 2</li>
<li>Advisory Board Agenda 3</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Now my questions are how do I make the list 'collapsed' not 'expanded' when the page loads as it displays already 'expanded' now? Also how do I link the elements inside of Minutes or Agendas (ie. Advisory Board Minutes 1, instead of the http://www.ccn.com can I just type the file's name and extension so when you click it, it will start to download).

Comment: Did you tried something yourself?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for JQuery accordion http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: There is no clear question asked. SO is a Q&A site.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a big deal actually, if you're OK with using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/).
Something like this:

```
$('#Minutes > li').click(function() {
    $('#Minutes ul').not($(this).find('ul')).stop(true,true).slideUp();
    $(this).find('ul').stop(true,true).slideDown(); list item
});
```

I've included comments in the fiddle of what every line does.
http://jsfiddle.net/tgs2x/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) jQuery methods with the `.click(function()` as well.